# Why won't the program exit?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Okay, so I was trying to convert a blocking network request to a non-blocking request. The library that I'm using for network I/O does provide functions to make asynchronous HTTP calls, but anyways, for the sake of experiments, I tried to do it this way:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mashape.unirest.request.GetRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class TestExecutorService {
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    static volatile Thread innerThread;

    public static void asyncGet (String url) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                innerThread = Thread.currentThread();
                GetRequest request = Unirest.get(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse <String> response = request.asString();
                    System.out.println(response.getBody());
                    Unirest.shutdown();
                } catch (UnirestException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestExecutorService.asyncGet("https://stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println("We're already here!");

        try {
            // Delay so that executor service's thread object could be
            // ...assigned to static variable innerThread
            Thread.sleep(100);
            TestExecutorService.innerThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a pro programmer and an absolute beginner when it comes to concurrency, and even I could tell that this piece of code can be improved, at least bit (one of those feelings you have as a beginner when you know something is wrong, but not sure what is). Anyways, what confuses me about the code above is that the program does not terminate. I didn't expect that to happen. I read a bit about `Executors.singleThreadExecutor` and I have an idea that if the inner thread dies for some reason, it creates a new thread and "transports" the state safely to the newly created thread. I've no clue why the program does not terminate though. Can someone give some hints?

**Please note that the code provided here will not be used in production environments. I wrote this just for practice.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two patterns.

If you are using `executor`s, you don't need to join. That thread was started by a system thread, not your main thread. It is not your child thread, actually you *cannot* `join` it. Just fire and forget.

If you create the thread yourself, then run it, you should `join` it. Then the child thread is yours.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the `innerThread` variable and calling `shutdown` on `executor` after the call to `asyncGet` in main seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the thread in your executor service is not a daemon thread. If you supply a `ThreadFactory`when you create your executor, then it should work.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, 
  new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
      Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory.newThread(r);
      t.setDaemon(true);
      return t;
   }
});
```

This will produce a executor service with daemon threads. 
You also have a bit of a race condition with your 'sleep'.
Instead of `join`, use a `CountdownLatch`.

Comment: Yes...I am aware of the possible race condition but since the program is sufficiently small, and I shall get a NullPointerException if that happens, I decided to put the thread to sleep for some time. Anyways, thanks. I'll have to look up what are daemon threads :)